ADO yaml pipeline - Iterating over a splitted string fails
I am scratching my head about the following pipeline and can't really figure out what the issue is.
I have the following yaml pipeline (code stripped to the issue):
stages:
- stage: Check

  variables:
    - name: trackBranch
      value: 'theBranch'

  jobs:
  - job: Checking
    displayName: Check branch

    steps:
    - powershell: |
        git fetch --depth=2 origin +refs/heads/${{ variables.trackBranch }}:refs/remotes/origin/${{ variables.trackBranch }}
        $diffFolders=git diff --name-only HEAD^ HEAD | ForEach-Object { $_.Trim() } | ForEach-Object { [System.IO.Path]::GetDirectoryName($_) } | Sort-Object -Unique
        
        Write-Output "Updated folders: $diffFolders"

        $namesArray = @()
        foreach ($entry in $diffFolders) {
          $namesArray += $entry
        }
        $names = $namesArray -join ','
        $namesAsString = $names | Out-String
        Write-Output "##vso[task.setvariable variable=changedFolders;isOutput=true]$namesAsString"
      displayName: 'searching'
      name: compare

  - job: Iteration
    dependsOn: Checking
    variables:
      - name: updatedMods
        value: $[dependencies.Checking.outputs['compare.changedFolders']]
      - name: testMods
        value: "mod1,mod2,mod3"
    steps:
      - script: |
          echo $(updatedMods)

      - ${{ each entry in split(variables.updatedMods, ',') }}:
        - script: echo ${{ entry }}
          displayName: "Processing ${{ entry }}"
      
      - ${{ each entry in split(variables.testMods, ',') }}:
        - script: echo ${{ entry }}
          displayName: "Processing ${{ entry }}"


In the first job it is comparing two commits from a branch, to find out if something got updated. For example it would return an object with the content: folder2 folder5 folder8, because these folders got changed. Then I am "forcing" it into a string write it to the variable 'changedFolders'.
In the next job, the variable gets echoed and I can see the content of the variable as expected. But the iteration part is failing with:

dependencies.Checking.outputs['compare.changedFolders']: Syntax error: Invalid arithmetic operator. (Error causing character is ".Checking.outputs['compare.changedFolders']")

But the iteration and splitting with the testMods is working fine.
So either I don't see where the issue is or the "received" variable in the second job is not really a string and is causing the trouble.
I searched for similar issues here on SO, but did not find a similar issue.

This is because the each loop ${{ each entry in split(variables.updatedMods, ',') }} is a template expression, which is processed at compile time. Anything that happens after the pipeline starts running is after template compilation. So, the value of variable updatedMods is defined at the compile time with this string  $[dependencies.Checking.outputs['gitCompare.changedFolders']].  It will not changed to the output value from job 1.
For more information, you can refer to Runtime expression syntax.
As a workaround, you can iterate over and split the string $(updatedMods) in a task.
Sample task:
      - script: |
          echo $(updatedMods)

          # Use a for loop to iterate over each item in the string
          for folder in $(updatedMods)
          do
            echo $folder
          done


Test result:

Update:

I have to figure out something else, because in each iteration some executions of further tasks should happen. (not only echoing stuff).

I can share another workaround. In this workaround, the two jobs in your current pipeline will run in separate pipelines.
In pipeline one, your job: Checking runs and you will get the diff folders. Then we can use the Runs - Run Pipeline REST API in the job to run the pipeline two and pass the diff folders value to the pipeline two. In pipeline two, you can set a Runtime parameter. The parameter value is passed from the pipeline one.
If that's acceptable to you, the following are the specific steps.

Pipeline one yaml:

trigger:
- none
stages:
- stage: Check

  variables:
    - name: trackBranch
      value: 'main'
  jobs:
  - job: Checking
    displayName: Check branch
    steps:
    - powershell: |
        # your steps to get the diff folders here
        $diffFolders="folder11,folder52,folder82" 
       
        $organization = "your organization name"
        $project="your projectname"
        $pipelineId=49    # you can find the pipeline definition Id of pipeline two from the pipeline URL.        

        $body = @"
        {
            "templateParameters": {
                "Mods": "$diffFolders"
            }
        }
        "@
        $response = Invoke-RestMethod "https://dev.azure.com/$organization/$project/_apis/pipelines/$($pipelineId)/runs?api-version=6.1-preview.1" -Method 'POST' -Headers @{Authorization = "Bearer $(System.AccessToken)"} -Body $Body -ContentType application/json
        $response | ConvertTo-Json



Pipeline two yaml. You can add your further tasks in pipeline two.

trigger:
- none

pool:
  vmImage: ubuntu-latest

parameters:
- name: Mods
  type: string
  default: []
steps:
- ${{ each entry in split(parameters.Mods, ',') }}:
  - script: echo ${{ entry }}
    displayName: "Processing ${{ entry }}"


Note: You should add your build service account the permission to Edit queue build configuration and Queue builds of pipeline two. Otherwise, you may see errors like "message": "TF215106: Access denied. projectname Build Service (orgname) needs Queue builds permissions for build pipeline 49 in team project to perform the action.



Test result: Pipeline two is triggered by pipeline one and get the Mods value from pipeline one.



Thank you, understood your explanation and what the problem is. Then I have to figure out something else, because in each iteration some executions of further tasks should happen. (not only echoing stuff).
Anyways your explanation was very helpful for understanding!

Hi @Bernte, I understand that you may have further tasks. I updated my answer to share another workaround. Please check the Update. Thanks!

Hi @Miao Tian-MSFT, thanks for the update! I will take a closer look at your approach. Right now I am using a combination of parallel job execution and templates, which also gave me what I needed. But your idea sounds promising, too.

TL;DR you're trying to access a variable set at runtime (value: $[ ... ]) in a template expression (${{ each ... }}), which is processed at compile time.
See Expressions and Understand variable syntax
More details
In short:

Variable updatedMods value ($[ dependencies.xxxx ]) is processed at runtime
Variable testMods value is static and available at compile time
Template expressions ${{ ... }} are processed ad compile time
Macro syntax $(updatedMods) is processed at runtime, before the task starts

So this means that when the pipeline is compiled, updatedMods's value has not yet been processed so this part will fail:
 - ${{ each entry in split(variables.updatedMods, ',') }}:
   - script: echo ${{ entry }}
     displayName: "Processing ${{ entry }}"


Workaround
Do the split as part of the script task:
- script: |
    MODS="$(updatedMods)"
    echo "MODS: $MODS"

    IFS=',' read -ra MODS <<< "$MODS"
    for i in "${MODS[@]}"; do
      echo "Processing $i"
    done
  displayName: "Processing updated mods"

Running the pipeline:


Also thanks to you. You basically gave the same explanation as Miao Tian-MSFT. But also helpful for understanding!
I have to figure out something else then, because in each iteration some executions of further tasks should happen. (not only echoing stuff).

@Bernte yeah only when I posted my answer and refreshed the page I've noticed Miao's answer :-)
